# custom directive parameters declaration differences

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am wondering about the differences between declaring custom directive parameters in these three ways :

**js :**

```
app.directive('customDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope : {
            x  :  '=',
            y  :  '=y',
            z  :  '=?'
        } , 
    }     
});
```

I am monitoring the three seems same behavior.
Can anyone help ?

Comment: I just know that the documentation say that if you put '=' the name of the var will be used. So y : '=' and y : '=y' are the sames

Comment: @Okazari yes but i think there is more into it than just alias ,, like initial load ,, also the =? i read it is optional params ... but the behaviour is the same ! so what if it was required and what if it was optional .. hope will get some help on that thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is the usual two-way data-binding, which means if you say `x : '='` the attribute on the element has to be `x` as well.

The second is an alternative to the first one with the difference that you can map the scope variable to a different attribute. For example you could say `y: '=foo'`. This maps the attribute `foo` to `y`.

With the last one you specify optional attributes, so you don't have to pass them along (not required).

For more information check the AngularJS documentation on `$compile` [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-).

TL;DR

> = or =attr - set up bi-directional binding between a local scope property and the parent scope property of name defined via the value
>   of the attr attribute. If no attr name is specified then the attribute
>   name is assumed to be the same as the local name. Given  and widget definition of scope: {
>   localModel:'=myAttr' }, then widget scope property localModel will
>   reflect the value of parentModel on the parent scope. Any changes to
>   parentModel will be reflected in localModel and any changes in
>   localModel will reflect in parentModel. If the parent scope property
>   doesn't exist, it will throw a NON_ASSIGNABLE_MODEL_EXPRESSION
>   exception. You can avoid this behavior using =? or =?attr in order to
>   flag the property as optional. If you want to shallow watch for
>   changes (i.e. $watchCollection instead of $watch) you can use =* or
>   =*attr (=*? or =*?attr if the property is optional).

**Edit:** I think the documentation is outdated because the exception appears to be thrown only in older revisions of the `$compile` source. In newer versions of AngularJS required scope properties which do not exist will be `undefined`.

**Edit 2:** As I have mentioned before that a newer version of Angular won't throw a `NON_ASSIGNABLE_MODEL_EXPRESSION` exception anymore you will still get an error whenever you try to assign a value to an optional property which is not defined on the element.

Comment: thanks @LordTribul so does that mean the directive wont work if i did not pass a required param ? i want to know the differant behaviour between required and optional coz really its working if i dont pass either

Comment: I just updated my answer. Maybe this clarifies your question.

Comment: You won't get an error immediately, but as soon as you try to assign a value, which is the very point of two-way binding. On the other hand, if you define an attribute as optional and it's missing, then there's no two-way binding in the first place.

Comment: yes i am using the 1.4 version and i am not having any error that is very accurate of you thanks for the answer .@LordTribual

Comment: @zeroflagL Thanks for the useful comment this makes it clearer :)

Comment: @zeroflagL Great additional information! I will update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

`=` and `=y` are the same.
 You can define different scope and html-attribute names like

```
scope:{
  a: '=b'
}
```

With this you would bind the html-attribute `b`to the scope value `a`

`=?` is an optional binding. So the attribute isnt required

Comment: what is the difference in the behaviour if i dont pass a required ,, and if i dont pass an optional ?

Comment: look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yA2rn/) you get an error if you don't pass a required attribute

Comment: Only in older versions of AngularJS. Check out my answer.

Comment: Thanks @TobiasTimm for the example yes i am using the new version and not facing the error